# Amazon textract custom adapters

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have developed an adapter for my business use-case using the Amazon Textract service. I have trained my adapter using a deep learning model provided by Textract. It is working fine in the console.

However, when I use my adapter with the `analyze_document()` api or `start_document_analysis()` api in AWS Lambda I am getting invalid parameter for `AdaptersConfig` as error.

Following is the url I referred:-
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/textract/client/analyze_document.html

Let me know if anyone has any leads

Thanking for your Support

I am expecting my adapter to integrate with Textract API's and extract the data.
But not able to find the solution.

Current logic i am using is below:-

````
            Document={
                'S3Object': {
                    'Bucket': bucket,
                    'Name': key,
                    'Version': versionID
                }
            },
            FeatureTypes=['QUERIES'],
            QueriesConfig={
                'Queries': [
                        {"Text": "When is the event?"}
                    ]
            },
            AdaptersConfig={
                'Adapters': [
                    {
                        'AdapterId': '1234567',
                        'Version': '3'
                    }
                    ]
            }
        )```
I am getting the below error:-
Failed extraction. Exception: Parameter validation failed:
Unknown parameter in input: "AdaptersConfig", must be one of: Document, FeatureTypes, HumanLoopConfig, QueriesConfig
````

Comment: Please Edit your question to include the code you are using and the _exact_ error message.

Answer (score 0):

AdaptersConfig was added in version 1.28.63 of boto3. You can view the changelog here:

https://github.com/boto/boto3/blob/develop/CHANGELOG.rst

I'm guessing you are using an earlier version. You can view older documentation by updating the url to match the version you are using:
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.28.62/reference/services/textract/client/analyze_document.html#

Update and try again!